# IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an scanning module which is working fine on my own windows 8.1 machine  but while publishing the code on IIS on window server 2012 I am facing with following error.

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I have registered successfully wiaaut.dll (64bit) but I am still facing the same issue.

Following is my code;

```
private ADFScan _scanner;
public EmpDetail()
{
    _scanner = new ADFScan();
}
protected void scan_Doc()
{
    _scanner.Scanning += new EventHandler<WiaImageEventArgs>(_scanner_Scanning);
    _scanner.ScanComplete += new EventHandler(_scanner_ScanComplete);
    ScanColor selectedColor = ScanColor.Color;
    int dpi = 150;//some scanners have a problem if you set a lower DPI
    _scanner.BeginScan(selectedColor, 150);
    //ADFScan will now raise a Scanning event for EACH document scanned.
    //then scan complete once there are no more documents to scan.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**

The possible workaround is modify your project's platform from 'Any CPU' to 'X86' (in Project's Properties, Build/Platform's Target)

**ROOTCAUSE**

The VSS Interop is a managed assembly using 32-bit Framework and the dll contains a 32-bit COM object. If you run this COM dll in 64 bit environment, you will get the error message.